# Instructions to comment on duplicate is out-of-date

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, duplicate-questions, documentation

The page [Cast Close And Reopen Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), has this section:

> #### Alternatives to closing
>
> If you don't have enough reputation to cast close votes, or have used
>   up your close votes for the day, there are alternatives:
>
> - If the question is a duplicate, post a comment with a link to the original.
> - If the question has serious problems (e.g. it is spam or offensive), flag it instead.

This implies that flagging is available for spam or offensive, but not comments. Perhaps this was once the case; however, currently you can flag duplicates as well. The directions should be updated to instruct users who can't cast close votes to flag duplicates.

Comment: What about users who've run out of close votes? They can't flag duplicates (at least not in the automated way)...

Comment: @animuson Even if you run out of close votes, you still have your 10 flags per day plus bonus flags, right? This section isn't talking about running out of flags.

Comment: If you have the vote to close privilege, you cannot flag to close, which includes the duplicate flag. They would have to use the "other" flag, which we do **not** want to encourage.

Comment: @animuson I just got the vote to close (which is why I read the "Cast Close And Reopen Votes" page to begin with). I get a Close link and a Flag link, both of which present the full set of choices, including duplicate.

Comment: Going through the flag menu will not actually create a flag. It will convert to an actual close vote, or error out if you're out of close votes.

Answer (score 1):

As [animuson noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/instructions-to-comment-on-duplicate-is-out-of-date#comment632798_199280), the description is actually correct. When you've maxed out your close votes for a day, you won't be able to flag a question for closure. Non-closing related flags are still an option, but the best course of action for duplicates when you've run out of close votes really is just to leave a comment pointing to the dupe so future visitors can know that the question is answered elsewhere (and can perhaps vote to close the question themselves).